# What type of cable can give the highest data transfer rate for an iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, usb, thunderbolt, data-transfer, lightning

I have an iPhone 5s and a 2020 Mac mini with

> Two Thunderbolt / USB 4 ports with support for:
>
> - DisplayPort
> - Thunderbolt 3 (up to 40 Gb/s) USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gb/s)
> - Thunderbolt 2, HDMI, DVI, and VGA supported using adapters (sold separately)
>
> Two USB-A ports (up to 5 Gb/s)

I searched that the iPhone 5s has a lightning port. I don't know much about lightning ports working with thunderbolt ports or USB 3, so I don't want to buy something with fast data transfer rate but only to be limited by the data transfer rate of iPhone 5s's lightning port.

So what type or types of cable can give the highest data transfer rate for an iPhone 5s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 5S offers USB 2.0 over its Lightning connector (USB 2.0 high speed maxes out at 480 Mbit/s ~ 0.5 Gb/s).

You will need either a USB-A to Lightning cable or a USB-C to Lightning cable. Combined with your current Mac Mini, either will give you the highest data transfer rate possible with the iPhone 5S.

Comment: So regardless of whether it's USB-A or USB-C it's going to be capped at the Lightning speed of 480 Mbit/s, right?

Comment: Yes.............